# How to read list of files from a folder an export into database in Grails

Tags: grails

I have lots of files of same type like .xml in a folder. How can I select this folder from interface and iterate over each file and send this to appropriate tables of database.
Thanks
Sonu

Comment: Are the files on the server or on the client computer?

Comment: Why are you yelling? Grails isn't an acronym, it's just 'Grails'.

Comment: These all files are on server itself. I have to fill database with these same type of file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you always put the files in the same directory? For example, if you generate these files in some other system, then just want the data imported into your application you could:

1. Create a job that runs every X minutes
2. It iterates over each file in the directory and parses the XML, creating and saving the objects to the database
3. Shifts or deletes the files when it has processed them

Jobs are a Grails concept/plugin: http://www.grails.org/Job+Scheduling+(Quartz)

Processing XML is easy in Groovy - you have many options, depends on your specific scenario - http://groovy.codehaus.org/Processing+XML

Processing files is also trivial - http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFile(groovy.lang.Closure)

This is a high level overview. Hope it helps.